# Nunit malfunction for tests in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have transitioned my test project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015.

Execution of the tests in earlier version was fine since it was `Mbunit`. In the new version is used `Nunit 3.4.1`. I do not see any problem in my code. Whenever I want to run test I receive Message: `No arguments were provided.`

Here is the code of test that have worked fine with `MbUnit`

```
 [Test]
 [TestCaseId(456123)]
 [Priority(PriorityLevel.Critical)]

 public void ExpiredJobViewPageUi(string channel, SeleniumWebDriverDeviceType seleniumWebDriverDeviceType,string widgetType) {
     TestRunner.RunTest(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), channel, seleniumWebDriverDeviceType, webDriver => {
         //Test body
         ReportLog.WriteLine("Step 1 - Create new flow.");
         var flow = new StandardFlowModel<JobModel>(channel, webDriver, ReportLog.WriteLine);

         ReportLog.WriteLine("Step 2 - Go to .");
         var expPage = flow.GoToExpirationPage(123);
         expPage.WaitPageIsLoaded(10);
         ....
```

When I click on `Run Selected Test` in the Text Explorer in Visual Studio 2015 I got the message `No arguments were provided`.

Can anybody help me what is wrong? Even though there is no chance to set break point to figure out what is going on.

Comment: You are expecting the parameters `string channel, SeleniumWebDriverDeviceType seleniumWebDriverDeviceType,string widgetType` but where are you providing them

Comment: Yes as CarbineCoder says, "No arguments were provided" is an accurate message. However, in addition, the above code would not compile if you replaced the reference to mbunit with one to the nunit framework. Do you have a different version that compiles using NUnit? Or are you trying to run tests compiled against mbuint using an NUnit runner?

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that I missed some input parameters in [] brackets. When I dig into TestRunner and debugged it I found that I need to specify `[Combination("parm", SeleniumWebDriverDeviceType.Desktop, "Popular Articles")]`
Thank you for your hints!